# pac file SyntaxError: Unexpected number issue

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to make a PAC file to direct users to bypass proxy if the destination hostname is local , if the destination hostname is public it will distribute traffic for 2 proxies. and if 2 proxies are down it will go direct and bypass the proxies. it gives me SyntaxError: Unexpected number but i can't find any syntax error.

```
 function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
 

    //if local domains match return direct 
    if (isInNet(host, "172.16.0.0", "255.240.0.0") || isInNet(host, "192.168.0.0", "255.255.255.0" ) || isInNet(host, "10.0.0.0", "255.0.0.0") )
          {          
          return "DIRECT";  
          }else {
              
                  // Find the 4th octet
                   var myip=myIpAddress()
                   var ipbits=myip.split(".")
                   var myseg=parseInt(ipbits[3])

                  // Check to see if the 4th octect is even or odd
                  if (myseg==Math.floor(myseg/2)2) {
                  // Even
                  proxy = "PROXY p1.company.com:8080; PROXY p2.company.com:8080 DIRECT";
                  }
                  else {
                  // Odd
                  proxy = "PROXY p2.company.com:8080; PROXY p1.company.com:8080 DIRECT";
                  }
              }   
 }
```

Comment: `if (myseg==Math.floor(myseg/2)2)` is invalid. What is that last `2` supposed to do?

Comment: it will distinguish between odd and even , if you try 5 for ex it will output 4 so this number will not be = to myseg which is the 4 octect in client ip address , i forget the * here

Comment: Generally we use `myseg % 2 === 0` to check if a number is even. That being said, fixing it should resolve your syntax error. Please don't fix it in your post, because that way  the mentioned error makes no sense anymore.

Comment: ok ,sorry i will not update the code , but i added var proxy to my code but it give me undefined

Comment: That changes the question completely. Given that this question has no answers yet, I don't object it being edited. But make sure the question as a whole makes sense. The "SyntaxError: Unexpected number" doesn't apply anymore.

Comment: That being said, it returns undefined because you are not returning `proxy` anywhere. You probably could just change `proxy = ...` into `return ...`.